# Изменение размера окна выполняет какое-либо функцию

Tags: python, tkinter

как можно сделать так, чтобы при изменении размера окна tkinter(а) с помощью мышки(таскать ее за уголок) выполнялась функция?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("400x300")

def callback(event): # функция, которая выполняется, когда размер окна именён
    #или окно перемещено
    print("Размер изменён!")

root.bind("<Configure>", callback) #само событие вызывается, если изменить размер

root.mainloop()
```

Также эта функция выполнится один раз при старте программы